# Windows 10 explorer crashes if shortcut to unreachable network location

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-shortcut

This is my scenario: I have a laptop with Windows 10 joined to an Active Directory Domain, with some shortcut and links to directory on some servers. When I'am connected to the Domain network everything is fine, but sometimes it happens that I use my laptop outside that network location.

In theese last days when I open a folder that contains a link to a network location (not the network location itself, even the desktop) explorer crashes and restart. If I connect my PC through a VPN, everithing is fine.

This happens also with the quick access link, so it's impossible to have some links to anything outside my pc because it keeps on restarting explorer.

I notice that if I delete the remote shortcut from my desktop, this directory works fine, it seems like if windows tries to reach the location of each file in the current directory even if I don't even select them, simply by refreshing or opening the directory.

The strangest thing is that problems start only few days ago, and I've made no changes that seems related to network or similar things. Before everything was fine (except that the mapped network drive cause me some problems, and that's why I use shotrcut instead).

What can be the problem? How can I solve it or what other test can I do to identify what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible your Sysadmin made some changes via GPOs? You should contact them as a first step.

Comment: I asked, but no changes have been made...

Comment: capture and share a crash dump and I'll take a look at it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: have you captured the dump?